# What's the most popular code snippet platform for iPhone/iPad?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, code-snippets

I'm wondering which platform do iPhone/iPad developers make use of or contributions to, like [Snippler](http://snipplr.com/) for instance. Instead of searching every code snippet platform for the number of iPhone tagged snippets (in fact I did search 6-7 platforms and could come up with just Snippler), I wanted to get your choices and your reasons behind.

Comment: Not that I don't like the question, but this is borderline off topic. It's also bordeline subjective. This may be better for pgogrammers.

Comment: I did that too, but 3x more people viewed my question here, than on Programmers. So I guess SO guys are the right audience.

Comment: Then perhaps it's off topic altogether.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**This is a great question, thanks!**

I personally have not even heard of Snipplr, which seems like a good idea.

I would tentatively tell you that it is not popular / unknown with iPhone peoples.

I'm inclined to believe actually StackOverflow is the best place for snippets.

FTR, **every single time** I have found a snippet useful to me, it has been from Stack Overflow !

For now, **I actually think the answer is "stackoverflow".** Hope it helps.

Comment: yeah that would be fantastic! Unfortunately for now I can only give an up vote for you :]

Comment: Oh someone did that for IntelliJ IDEA: http://snipplr.com/developer/